# How to access a button inside a <div> container using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to access a button inside a 'div' tag but the problem is, there are two 'div' tags with same class name and one of them has the button. So how to identify which one has the button and access it. So far I tried to solve but I always get 'Unable to locate element' for button.

One is:

```
div class="weEq5" style="will-change; width;"
```

Another one is:

```
div class="weEq5"
    button class="_35EW6"
```

Comment: Share your code and HTML (with markup, not as just simplified text)

Answer (score 1):

To find `div` contain `button`, first you need to select the `button` then go to parent element which is `div`

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button/parent::div[@class="weEq5"]')
# or
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="_35EW6"]/parent::div[@class="weEq5"]')
```

Comment: You seem to be using BeautifulSoup syntax while OP is looking for Selenium solution

Comment: my bad it is because I have multiple tab, @Andersson thanks for telling.

Answer (score 0):

To access the button inside the `<div>` you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class]:not(style)>button"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class and not (@style)]/button")
  ```